# messages not even appears on the RabbitMQ server

Tags: java, rabbitmq, producer-consumer

In my RabbitMQ app the producer sends messages, but consumer receives only part of them(not the biggest one). when I execite `rabbitmqctl list_queues` in terminal it shows:

```
~$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...    
MdnaMessagesQueue   0
...done.
```

which means that messages are lost going to the queue or they were taken from the queue very fast. so I can't understand why this happens. I have no other apps which could get messages from that queue. here is my producers code:

```
public class Sender {
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "MdnaMessagesQueue";

    public void send(byte[] message) throws IOException {

        AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder bob = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder();
        AMQP.BasicProperties minBasic = bob.build();
        AMQP.BasicProperties minPersistentBasic = bob.deliveryMode(2).build();

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection(service);
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, message);
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using the management plugin.  It can help with visualizing these issues.

Comment: After PC reboot the problem disapeared and I've never faced with it anymore. Mabe there were a process which have been "eating" messages.

Comment: Maybe you had not enough disk space?